# most common android devices for each

Tags: android, mobile, android-testing

There is a fair amount of information available on Android operating system version adoption and which versions are most common (ex. [here](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html))

Is there a resource containing similar information about physical device characteristics based on popularity?  That is, for example, which screen sizes are most common, etc?

Comment: I think this is a good question, although I think there might be a way to clarify/simplify a bit.  I'm going to propose an edit, feel free to rollback if I've butchered your original intent.

Comment: I was actually more interested in specific devices so I know which ones I can purchase and do physical testing on to help me feel more confident about compatibility but no you didn't butcher it too much :)

Answer (score 0):

From the link you quote http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html:

```
Size        ldpi    mdpi    hdpi    xhdpi
small       1.1%    N/A     1.7%    N/A
normal      0.4%    11.4%   51.9%   22.3%
large       0.1%    2.5%    N/A     3.9%
xlarge      N/A     4.7%    N/A     N/A
```

And from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html:

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

I am not aware of any resource that will tell you other metrics like how many devices have a front facing camera or only have a front facing camera etc..

Comment: As mentioned before, I was actually more curious about actual devices :)  An example being: ICS 4.0.3-4.0.4 API 15: 20% --> { Galaxy S3: 80%, Nexus: 20% }.  If that makes sense.